# Vue with Axios drop down pre populate

Tags: vue.js, axios, dropdown

I'm trying to figure out how to pre-populate my vue drop down.

When I click on the drop down it doesn't show anything, but when I click off of it and back on it, it will show the options. This is not the behavior I want. I would like it to show the options when clicking on it once.

```
 <template>
  <select  v-model='selectedApp' @click="populateApp(results)">
  <option value="" disabled> Select an application</option>
  <option v-for="result in results">{{ result.name }} {{result.id}}</option>  
 </select>
</template>
<script>

import axios from 'axios'

 export default{
  data(){
   return {
    selectedApp: '',
    results: []
   }
  },
  methods: {

      populateApp: function(event){
      axios.get('/apdata',{params: {query: this.query}})
      .then(response => {
      this.results = response.data;
      console.log(this.results);
     });
   
   }
  }
 }

</script>
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this. And you forgot to bind the `value` to option. Here's [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5vzcfx)

```
<template>
    <div>
      <select v-model="selectedApp">
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose</option>
        <option v-for="result in results" :value="result.id">{{ result.name }} {{ result.id }}</option>
      </select>
      <div>selectedApp: {{ selectedApp }}</div>
    </div>
 </template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
       selectedApp: "",
       results: []
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
       const response = await axios.get('/apdata', { params: { query: this.query } })
       this.results = response.data
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is you answer using @Naren suggested

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
 data() {
    return {
        selectedApp: '',
        results: []
    }
 },
 mounted() {
    axios.get('/apdata', {
            params: {
                query: this.query
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.results = response.data;
            console.log(this.results);
        })
 },
 props:{},
 ....
}
```

If you are using `nuxt` i suggest using `AsyncData` as it will automatically bind the data to the property to be used

```
async asyncData({ app, params }) {
  const { data } = await app.$axios.get(`path/${params.code}`)
  return { results: data.error ? [] : data } 

  //data(){ results:[] } does not need to be defined as this will be taken care of by asyncData
}
```

If you are using vuejs3 you will need to do the same thing as `mounted` hook except in setup() additionally you may need to import the router

```
  import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

  export default {
    setup(props, ctx) {
      const route = useRoute()

      onMounted(() => {
        const id = route.params.id


        ///add code here
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do I do with " @click="populateApp(results)" being that I don't have the method any more?

Comment: delete it - however this is a design choice - if you want the results to be immedtialty populated after render than `mounted` is your friend. If you want it on click - you need to keep the method - so which would you like to do?